# How can i seperate Serilog Properties outside of the Messagetemplate

Tags: c#, serilog

I am using Serilog in a private C# application. My Logging looks currently like:
`Log.Information("{Propertie1}{Propertie2}{Propertie3}",value1,value2,value)`

It works, but it is hard to read. The message now looks like "123" but now I want them to look like "1,2,3". Is there any way to fix this afterwards with Serilog's options? Because otherwise I must fix every Logmessage one by one.
Thanks in advance.

I did some research, but I didn't found a solution for this specific problem. Furthermore I only found example, here the separation is already in the message template. But before I wanted it to do it that, I wanted some expert advice.

Comment: Just put a comma between the tokens: `Log.Information("{Propertie1},{Propertie2},{Propertie3}",value1,value2,value)`

Comment: side-note, the correct spelling is "Property".

Comment: Hi! Serilog doesn't provide this directly, but it sounds a little bit like you're trying to standardize the eventual text output format (e.g. to console or file) via the messages themselves (it'd be strange to have a lot of log messages all using his format to update, otherwise). If that's the case, it's more than likely your problem can be solved using `ExpressionTemplate` from _Serilog.Expressions_. Posting some more details (five "whys" style possibly) about your scenario will help uncover any solutions along those lines. HTH!

Comment: Hi, everybody, sry for the late answer. This ExpressionTemplate sounds interesiting, but i am failing to integrate it. I have installed the package Serilog Expressions.
Now i have the problem, that i cant i used With serilog. 
Before i build the logger in the program.cs, i want to configure the sink with config.WriteTo.File(path, params[]). But this method doenst take any parameter which implements the ITextFormatter. So iam not sure how to integrate it.

Comment: And yeah i tried zto google it, but didnt found something so far.